# how to redirect Wheel events of QWidget to QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

when you turn the mouse wheel while the mouse is not on the QTextEdit ,the scroll bars will not move in such case ,but I still want to move the scroll bars by mouse wheel ,so how can I implement this function ?
I know some software like Microsoft Word have this feature .

I implement this feature like the following ,but when you move the scroll bars to the top or bottom by mouse wheel ,an error would occur : maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.
anyone can help ?
my code here http://codepad.org/1rq06qTk:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class BoxLayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 300)

        ok = QPushButton("OK")
        cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit("This function returns true if the contents "
                                  "of the MIME data object, specified by source, "
                                  "can be decoded and inserted into the document. "
                                  "It is called for example when during a drag "
                                  "operation the mouse enters this widget and it "
                                  "is necessary to determine whether it is possible "
                                  "to accept the drag and drop operation.")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(ok)
        vbox.addWidget(cancel)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

#       self.textEdit.installEventFilter(self)


#    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
#        if obj == self.textEdit:
#            if event.type() == QEvent.Wheel:
#                self.textEdit.wheelEvent(event)
#                return True
#            else:
#                return False
#        else:
#            return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.textEdit.wheelEvent(event)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = BoxLayout()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by installing an event filter on any widget which shall forward the mouse wheel event to the QTextEdit:

I can unfortunately only give you C++ code but it should give you a general idea.
Also, I'm using Qt 4.6.1. I've detected a new "Scroll" Event type in Qt 4.8 and later, you might have to change the code when using that.

---

[Edit:]

For TextEdit scrolling, event processing differs from the standard way for some reason:
Sending a Wheel Event to the Text Edit does not process it.
Instead, some kind of private event filter calls `wheelEvent` through `QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent` which is unfortunately protected.

Long story short, we can fake Wheel Events by subclassing QTextEdit:

```
#include "MyTextEdit.h"

MyTextEdit::MyTextEdit( QWidget* parent ) :
    QTextEdit( parent )
{
}

void MyTextEdit::forwardViewportEvent( QEvent* event )
{
    viewportEvent( event );
}
```

---

When using this instead of the default QTextEdits, you can create an Event Forwarder like this:

---

```
#ifndef WHEELEVENTFORWARDER_H
#define WHEELEVENTFORWARDER_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>

class MyTextEdit;

class WheelEventForwarder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WheelEventForwarder( MyTextEdit* target );
    ~WheelEventForwarder();

    bool eventFilter( QObject* obj, QEvent* event );

private:
    MyTextEdit* _target;
};

#endif // WHEELEVENTFORWARDER_H
```

---

WheelEventForwarder.cpp

```
#include "WheelEventForwarder.h"
#include "MyTextEdit.h"
#include <QtCore/QEvent>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

WheelEventForwarder::WheelEventForwarder( MyTextEdit* target ) :
    QObject(),
    _target( target )
{
}

WheelEventForwarder::~WheelEventForwarder()
{
    _target = NULL;
}

bool WheelEventForwarder::eventFilter( QObject* obj, QEvent* event )
{
    Q_UNUSED( obj );

    static bool recursionProtection = false;

    if( recursionProtection ) return false;

    if( !_target ) return false;

    if( event->type() == QEvent::Wheel )
    {
        recursionProtection = true;
        _target->forwardViewportEvent( event );
        recursionProtection = false;
    }

    // do not filter the event
    return false;
}
```

---

Then you can install an event filter like this:

MainWindow.cpp (or any better fitting place):

```
_wheelEventForwarder = new WheelEventForwarder( ui->textEdit );

ui->centralwidget->installEventFilter( _wheelEventForwarder );
```

See the documentation for [QObject::installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for more information on this.

Comment: I've been able to try it now and fixed some compilation errors + made the class more reusable. However event forwarding doesn't seem to work the way I expected, I'm looking into this at the moment.

Comment: I've made it work, at least for Qt 4.6.1. See my updated answer (It would be best to read it from the start again, I had to change a lot)

Comment: `recursionProtection` is a static variable, which means its value will be shared among all function calls. It is set to `true` before the call of `forwardViewportEvent` as this calls a couple of other functions which end up in `eventFilter` again. `recursionProtection` then prevents the function from being executed over and over again, which would otherwise result in an infinite loop. You could also use a member variable instead if you want.

Comment: thanks ,but how did you find out that forwardViewportEvent will result  in calling eventFilter again ?

Comment: I've tested it without recursion protection and got an infinite recursion error ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of Tim Meyer's C++ code from above in Python. This question is still relevant in Qt 5.15, despite it being an old question.

This code keeps the recursion detection, which may no longer be necessary for the latest release of Qt5. (I tested with 5.15.8, and it worked fine without it.)

Create a custom event filter class, similar to Tim's:

```py
class WheelEventFilter(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self._parent = parent
        self._locked = False
        return

    def eventFilter(self, object: QObject, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        """Filter events of type QWheelEvent and forward them to the
        parent widget's wheelEvent handler.
        """
        if self._locked:
            return False
        if isinstance(event, QWheelEvent):
            self._locked = True
            self._parent.wheelEvent(event)
            self._locked = False
        return False
```

Then, install the filter in the initialisation of the `QTextEdit` subclass:

```py
class TextEditor(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.installEventFilter(WheelEventFilter(self))

        return
```

This seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with this approach:

Call QTextEdit.scroll(int,int) function to scroll qtextedit whenever required.
Mean you can cal this function from the mouseScrollEvent of your widget

Comment: but there is no function named "mouseScrollEvent"

Comment: It is named with wheelEvent(). You can use this event for performing your task

Answer (score 0):

@TimMeyer's solution works well. At least for C++.

I stripped out the "recursion" guards. With Qt/v5.12,  it is not necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).