# redirect keyboard events to QTextEdit when it has no focus?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

when the QTextEdit doesn’t have focus ,how to redirect keyboard events to the text editor ?

my code is here
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30245/

thanks for your help !
I did want to intercept any key event at application level, I have also been told to use event filter at such case before ,but I have difficulty in implementing the eventFilter() function here ,can you show some code ?thanks in advance !

Comment: Does it not work exactly the same way as the wheel events in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738997/how-to-redirect-wheel-events-of-qwidget-to-qtextedit

Comment: Perhaps the same ,but I don't understand his code .can you show me some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an event filter to redirect it from another part of your application.

[Catching Qt modifier key releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747991/catching-qt-modifier-key-releases/11026014#11026014)

If your application is not focused at all, you would need to use a keyboard hook or something similar.

Hope that helps.

Comment: of course ,the precondition here is that the  app still has focus

Answer (score 0):

This is how eventFilter could be implemented into your code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class BoxLayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.resize(100, 300)

        ok = QPushButton("OK")
        cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(ok)
        vbox.addWidget(cancel)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.installEventFilter(self)





    def eventFilter(self, object_, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyRelease and self.focusWidget() != self.textEdit:
            self.textEdit.append(event.text())

        return False


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = BoxLayout()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to prevent other widgets from receiving the keys just return True in the event Filter